# Forzar Tipo Variable MongoDB (Java)

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Quisiera saber si existe algun metodo para "forzar" el tipo de variable dentro de **MongoDB** en **Java**.
Necesito insertar un `Document` con ciertos datos, ejemplo:

```
Document doc = new Document();
// Forzar que guarde Rut como Integer siendo que recibe un Strig
doc.append("RUT","123456789");
```

Alguien sabe algo?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que ocupas es convertir en el valor de `RUT` a `Integer` necesitas el método `parseInt` de la clase `Integer`, como en el siguiente código:

```
Document di = new Document();
//Se realiza la conversión del datos de String a Integer
di.append("RUT",Integer.parseInt("123456789"));
```